# PDF Math error with stock moderntimeline commands

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

I am trying to use the moderntimeline package for moderncv but pdflatex is giving me errors. All .sty files are stock. Here is a simple code that produces the error for me.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\tlmaxdates{2007}{2012}

\firstname{Lorem}
\familyname{Ipsum}

\begin{document}
\tllabelcventry[magenta]{2002}{2003}{July--November 2002}{Scribus Student}{GNU School}{The Internet}{}{Tried Scribus for a short while}
\end{document}
```

The error from the log reads `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'ifthenelse'.`

Here's what the PDF looks like:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I suspect a problem with file versions. Your example works for me. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Please add command `\listfiles` before `\documentclass ...` in your MWE and check the `log` file. Please add the list of used packages in your question. Your MWE runs on my MiKTeX 2.9 system without any errors ...

Comment: I am using 'pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)'

The list of packages was too long to paste into comment. Anything in particular I should be looking at in this log? Thanks!

Comment: May be you should consider upgrading to texlive 2012.

Comment: This is clearly a version issue, which makes it 'too localized' (in time) as updating will fix it.